# What is ACLLIST in Samba Configuration

Tags: linux, samba

I try to read some code in Linux for samba configuration, and I got confuse for some code, maybe some of friends in here could help me get through.

```
acllist=$ACLLIST
```

What is `acllist` and why it must declared like that?

and on every top of create user bash and build acl, it has something like this declared:

`. /opt/usr/script/etc/scriptvar`

while that contain this script:

```
ACLLIST=/etc/samba/useracl.list

WINMYDOCS=off

WINSERVER=192.168.1.205

SYNBAK=/var/backups

EDITOR=mcedit

IPSERVER=192.168.1.229

IPNET=192.168.1.0/24

IPPUB=

SMTPPRG=java
```

At some point, I am seeing this while creating user script:

```
edquota -p wilisystem $1 2>/dev/null
```

For now, that's the thing That I need to learn, 
Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried running the script without "$1 2>/dev/null"? The output will perhaps tell you more.

Comment: i know the code for 2>/dev/null mean put the output to null, but I can get anything with wilisystem, which I try to find and result on nothing,